# Implementation-specific questions about type erasure via external polymorphism

Tags: c++, type-erasure, argument-dependent-lookup

I have recently watched a [CppCon 2021 talk by Klaus Iglberger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eeESJQk-mw) about type erasure pattern and tried to implement it based on the slides. Despite the code from slides not compiling, after a lot of searching and reading SO answers I got an implementation that *seems* to work, but I have further questions.

First, the complete implementation is presented. `Shape` is an "external" interface that specifies a `draw()` requirement. `Circle` and `Square` adhere to this interface requirement and provide implementations in the form of free functions. Furthermore, one of the goals of type erasure is for `Shape` to have value semantics.

[Live on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xf3GzWzed)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class Circle {
   public:
    explicit Circle(double radius) : radius_(radius) {}

   private:
    double radius_;
};

class Square {
   public:
    explicit Square(double side) : side_(side) {}

   private:
    double side_;
};

void draw(Circle const& c) { std::cout << "Drawing a circle\n"; }
void draw(Square const& s) { std::cout << "Drawing a square\n"; }

class Shape {
    // Shape's interface is implemented as hidden friends.
    friend void draw(Shape const& shape) {
        // Dispatch in ShapeModel<ConcreteShape>::draw().
        shape.pimpl_->draw();
    }

    class ShapeConcept {
       public:
        virtual ~ShapeConcept() = default;

        // Shape's interface declaration.
        virtual void draw() const = 0;

        // Make ShapeConcept's children copyable through ShapeConcept pointer.
        [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const = 0;

       protected:
        ShapeConcept() = default;
        ShapeConcept(ShapeConcept const&) = default;
        ShapeConcept(ShapeConcept&&) noexcept = default;
        ShapeConcept& operator=(ShapeConcept&&) noexcept = default;
        ShapeConcept& operator=(ShapeConcept const&) = default;
    };

    template <typename ConcreteShape>
    class ShapeModel final : public ShapeConcept {
       public:
        explicit ShapeModel(ConcreteShape&& concrete_shape)
            // Copy-construct or move-construct the concrete type.
            : object_{std::forward<ConcreteShape>(concrete_shape)} {}

        void draw() const override {
            // Call free draw() on objects implementing the Shape interface.
            // XXX: why doesn't it work without scope resolution operator, by
            // ADL? draw(object_);
            ::draw(object_);
        }

        [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const override {
            return std::make_unique<ShapeModel>(*this);
        }

       private:
        ConcreteShape object_;
    };

   public:
    template <
        typename ConcreteShape,
        // Make sure that templated forwarding constructor does not hide the
        // copy constructor. Another very important thing is to decay the
        // ConcreteShape before comparison, otherwise Shape& binds to this
        // constructor.
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Shape, std::decay_t<ConcreteShape>>,
                         bool> = true>
    explicit Shape(ConcreteShape&& concrete_shape)
        // XXX: Do I need to remove_cvref of ConcreteShape before passing it to
        // make_unique?
        : pimpl_{std::make_unique<ShapeModel<ConcreteShape>>(
              std::forward<ConcreteShape>(concrete_shape))} {}

    // Deep copy of the concrete shape object.
    Shape(Shape const& other) : pimpl_{other.pimpl_->clone()} {}

    // Deep copy of the concrete shape object.
    Shape& operator=(Shape const& rhs) {
        if (&rhs != this) {
            pimpl_ = rhs.pimpl_->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // unique_ptr is movable by default.
    Shape(Shape&&) noexcept = default;
    Shape& operator=(Shape&&) noexcept = default;

    ~Shape() = default;

   private:
    // Pointer to a ShapeModel, which has a member object of the concrete type.
    std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> pimpl_;
};

void draw_all_shapes(std::vector<Shape> const& shapes) {
    for (auto const& shape : shapes) {
        // Call Shape's hidden friend draw() by ADL.
        draw(shape);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Does Shape behave like a value?

    Circle c{3};
    Shape s1{c};
    Shape s2{Circle{3.0}};
    Shape s4{Shape{Circle{3.0}}};
    Shape s5{std::move(s2)};
    Shape s6 = s5;

    std::vector<Shape> shapes;
    shapes.emplace_back(Circle{1.0});
    shapes.emplace_back(Square{2.0});
    draw_all_shapes(shapes);

    Shape s7 = Shape{Circle{3.0}};
    Shape s8{s7};
    const Circle c1{1};
    Shape s9{c1};
    const Shape s10{std::move(c1)};
    const Shape s11{Shape{Circle{1}}};
    const Shape s12{s11};
    Shape& s13 = s9;
    Shape const& s14 = s12;

    // Everything *seems* to work..., but does it?
}
```

And now the questions (marked with `XXX`), `ConcreteShape` is either a `Circle` or a `Square`:

1. `virtual Shape::ShapeModel<ConcreteShape>::draw()` is provided to dispatch to correct free `draw(ConcreteShape const&)` implementation somewhere else, that the `ConcreteShape` must provide. Currently it is implemented as `::draw(concrete_shape);`, which allows the inner `draw(ConcreteShape const&)` to be looked up in global namespace. However, if I put it inside a namespace, it will not compile. Regardless, I would have expected `draw(concrete_shape)` to work just fine and find `ConcreteShape`'s free implementation through ADL, and current implementation is a workaround. What went wrong, why doesn't the ADL work? And most importantly, is it possible to fix it, or do I have to hardcode the full path to exact namespace that has free implementations?
2. Moving on to `Shape`'s templated forwarding constructor. The talk does not show this, but based on the chapter about forwarding constructors in "Effective Modern C++" and other SO answers I have implemented a check for cvref-stripped type equivalence, so that an lvalue reference `Shape&` binds to the copy constructor instead. However, after debugging this problem I also realized that when `ConcreteShape` passed to `Shape` constructor is a reference, then the `object_` member of type `ConcreteShape` may also be a reference, and no copy will be made, which is probably unexpected. Is this assumption correct? Should I cvref-strip `ConcreteShape` before passing it to `make_unique`?

Finally, is this a correct implementation of the type erasure pattern, or did I miss something? Anything else you would change?

Comment: [A simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/sadM7P5bP) to reproduce stand-alone `draw` not being found by ADL lookup. Not yet sure why.

Comment: The easy workaround is to name the `ShapeConcept`'s virtual method something other than `draw`. Since it's internal, you can give it any name.

Comment: Your intuition is correct: with `Circle c{3}; Shape s1{c};`, `s1` ends up holding a reference to `c`, not a copy thereof. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/19W1qz3aj) (note the same address printed twice).